# Dynamic Navbar extracted from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The scenario is the following: You are building a `store app` where you have a `category` and a `product` model. Your `navbar` will contain the `categories` table dynamically. A **DRY** way of doing it would be to have to `every action` on your `products controller`:

`@categories = Category.all`

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a before_filter in the controller.

```
before_filter :get_categories

protected
def get_categories
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

Comment: You mean on every controller right; in case I have a static_pages controller as well? And should i have the method inside my model?

Comment: You only want this on the `ProductsController`, so no, this method is only is part of the `ProductsController`.
If you'd like it in the whole application then move this bit of code to the `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a small clarification if possible: I read that any method that deals with models e.g.scope, it's better to stay in the model rather than the controller. Does this apply here or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Say you'd like to define a method that will give you a specific scope of a model, for example the 3 most recent products which are online.
You could have it as `@newest_products = Product.where('online = ?', true).order('date DESC').limit(3)` in each controller or instead you could define a scope in your model `scope :newest_products, where('online = ?', true).order('date DESC').limit(3)` and then in your controllers instead just do `@newest_products = Product.newest_products`, if you use it a lot then it's worth a scope, and you still call it in the controller so you can show it in the view.